# Is RecyclerView.hasStableIds(true) grouped by itemViewType?

Tags: android, android-viewholder, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with an `RecyclerView.Adapter` whose backing data is coming from a `Cursor` via a `Loader`. The data contains two types of items: `A` and `B` returned via an `UNION ALL`. `getItemViewType` returns different `int`s for each (see note below). The `A` and `B` entities are from different SQLite database tables, and both theirs `_id` start from `1`, so it's very like that there'll be a `B` whose `_id` is the same as an existing `A` and vice versa.

**Is it safe to set `setHasStableIds(true)` on the above adapter?**
It it possible that a weird case might happen when the cursor has both As and Bs with the same ID and an animation or recycle goes wrong?

*Note:
All the other parts of the `Adapter` is pretty standard: `getItemViewType` is implemented by returning `R.layout.a_view` or `R.layout.b_view`. There are also separate `ViewHolder` subclasses for each type created in `onCreateViewHolder` with a switch on `itemViewType`.*

*All items are displayed correctly and even animate when I go away to another activity, modify some data and then press the back button (thanks to Loaders I guess).*